# ListView selected item and button interaction?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a ListView with several items as "stages" in a game, and one button that says "start stage". How can I check which item is selected at the button_click handler, so I can load the appropriate stage?

Note: Using VisualStudio (C#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dropdownlist1.selectedValue
```

Think that is what you are saying by how you phrased it

Comment: So let's say the item in my ListView is called stage1, and I want to check if stage1 is selected, how would I program this?

Comment: ListView1.SelectedItems. Why use a listview and not a dropdown if you only want to select 1 item?

Comment: Thanks! I could try the combobox out.

Comment: I can't get the selected items to work. 'if(ListView1.SelectedItems == stage1){ }' doesn't work. It needs a collection?